# Finding repeated substrings with R

Tags: r

I have the following code for finding out a pattern (consecutively repeated substring) in a string, say `0110110110000`. The output patterns are `011` and `110`, since they are both repeated within the string. What changes can be done to the following code?

I'd like to identify substrings that start from any position in a given string, and which repeat for at least a threshold number of times. In the above mentioned string, the threshold is three (`th = 3`). The repeated string should be the maximal repeated string. In the above string, `110` and `011` both satisfy these conditions.

Here's my attempt  at doing this:

```
reps <- function(s, n) paste(rep(s, n), collapse = "") # repeat s n times

find.string <- function(string, th = 3, len = floor(nchar(string)/th)) {
for(k in len:1) {
    pat <- paste0("(.{", k, "})", reps("\\1", th-1))
    r <- regexpr(pat, string, perl = TRUE)
    if (attr(r, "capture.length") > 0) break
}
if (r > 0) substring(string, r, r + attr(r, "capture.length")-1) else ""
}
```

Comment: "also meets all the requirements" ... What requirements?

Comment: to find a pattern from any position in any given string such that the pattern repeats for a threshold number of times at least.  In the above mentioned string threshold number(th = 3) also repeated string should be maximal repeated string. In the above string, 110 and 011 both are satisfying above mentioned conditions.

Comment: You should make all of that clear in the question itself, so that people don't have to read through comments to discover essential details.

Comment: What about `0000` in your example string? (That's four zeroes in a row.)

Comment: How long can a pattern be?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9216783/489704), although that post refers to substrings that repeat but aren't necessarily adjacent. It's also perl (using constructs that I believe aren't supported in R).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `regex`:

```
s <- '0110110110000'

thr <- 3

m <- gregexpr(sprintf('(?=(.+)(?:\\1){%s,})', thr-1), s, perl=TRUE)

unique(mapply(function(x, y) substr(s, x, x+y-1), 
              attr(m[[1]], 'capture.start'), 
              attr(m[[1]], 'capture.length')))

# [1] "011" "110" "0"
```

The pattern in the `gregexpr` uses a positive lookahead to prevent characters from being consumed by the match (and so allowing overlapping matches, such as with the `011` and `110`). We use a repeated (at least `thr - 1` times) backreference to the captured group to look for repeated substrings.

Then we can extract the matched substrings by taking start positions and lengths from the attributes of the result of `gregexpr`, i.e. the object `m`.

You didn't specify a minimum string length, so this returns `0` as one of the repeated substrings. If you have a minimum and/or maximum substring length in mind, you can modify the first subexpression of the regex. For example, the following would match only substrings with at least 2 characters.

```
sprintf('(?=(.{2,})(?:\\1){%s,})', thr-1)
```